# Adwords scripts image ads size

Tags: google-ads-api

I am writing a script to choose the best performing ad and deleting the rest.I want to pull ads based on size

Is there a way to pull the size of the image ad through adwords scripts?

Comment: can you show your code?  What is working, what isn't?

Comment: var reportIterator = AdWordsApp.report('SELECT Id,ImageCreativeName,Cost,Clicks,Conversions,ConversionRate,CostPerConversion,ConvertedClicks,CostPerConvertedClick,Ctr,Impressions FROM   AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT WHERE  CampaignName ="'+campName+'" AND AdGroupId="' + adgrpId + '" AND AdType="IMAGE_AD" DURING LAST_30_DAYS').rows();

Comment: @joelgoldstick I wrote this query: previouslu the imageCreativeName used to have the sixe details too .but for this particular client the naming convention is different.So just wanted to check if there is anyway to pull the size

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from the "AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT" if you pull the field "Headline" you get the Ad name and size.